# Fetch and write CLOB type values from oracle to a file

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I have some questions, and would like your help please:

I am trying to do some processing on data in python. But I need to connect to the db and get the data, about 300,000 rows of type CLOB. That column in the db has content (text), urls and html tags, thats how they have it set up, I cant change that. My project (Phase one) is to go through that column in the table in the db and extract URLs, I am using beautifulSoup for url extraction, i have that part done. But just getting the data (CLOB) out of the db and storing it into a file (I guess it doesn't have to be csv, I am the one decided to try csv) Thats what I am having problems with.
This is how a row of data would look like after fetching it with my code, notice the extra double quotes, in the actual db there is one double quote only:

()

here is my code:

```
import csv  
import cx_Oracle

sql = """select target_values from temp_ip_url_backup""";  
filename="results.csv"   
results=csv.writer(FILE, dialect='excel')  
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('db connection stuff')  
cursor = connection.cursor()  
cursor.execute(sql)  
rows = cursor.fetchall()  
for row in rows:  

    results.writerow(row) 

cursor.close()  
connection.close()  
FILE.close()
```

First question: Why is the file coming back with doubled double quotes?
Second question: I understand that the result is coming back as Tuples, how do i convert it to string and store it in a file?

Your answers are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why is there html in csv file? please provide meaningful example data with your questions.

Comment: update your question with that information and delete your comments